# How can I update a record if it is added to an association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this data structure:

```
Root
  Child
    Child
  Child
    Child
      Child
  Child
```

My models are set up like this:

- Root: has_many :children
- Child: has_many :children, belongs_to :root

For some tasks every child has a back reference to the Root record.

**How can I make sure, every time a new a child gets inserted, the root reference gets updated to?**

Currently only the immediate children are set correctly:

- `c = Root.children.new` --> `root_id` is set
- `c.children.new` --> `root_id` is `nil` (understandably)

I suspect I can only do this manually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually, yes.  But it's still a clear and clean way of expressing what you're trying to do.

`c.children.new(:root_id => c.root_id)`